# Refresh a specific class after post ajax Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, symfony

So after lot of researchs, I come here to request your help, there is my problem :

I have a comment system with multiple forms on a same page (I use FOSCommentBundle on Symfony). And I want to be able to post comments with Ajax (this part work, no problems) and refresh the comment section after the post is submitted (And i'm stuck on this part).

There is an example of code :

```js
$(document).on("submit", ".postAjax", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).LoadingOverlay("show");
    data = $(this).serializeObject();

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(){
            $(".comments").load(window.location.href + " .comments");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" class="postAjax" action="./comment/post/1">
  <input type="textarea" name="comment">
  <input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="1">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
 <div class="comments">
   <!-- Comments refreshed after post here -->
 </div>
 
 <form method="POST" class="postAjax" action="./comment/post/2">
  <input type="textarea" name="comment">
  <input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="2">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
 <div class="comments">
   <!-- Comments refreshed after post here -->
 </div>
 
 <!-- ... -->
```

I have tried lot of things, the function ".load" of JQuery but it load all the "comments" class and duplicate the comments in each class.

If someone have a solution... Thank you

Comment: Use `ajax` instead of load. Once the response is received append the response to the existing. It depend on the response sent from middle layer. If it is sending only the last comment , you can update that,

Comment: @brk Thank you but the problem is the response is not only the comment but the whole page, so I can't use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in the provided code, your `<form>` tag lack an action attribute for your code to work properly.

Then, to answer your question, modify your controller action (the one saving your new comment) so that it return the informations of the submitted comment (json format is better). Then, transform the returned json into html code, and append the result to your comments `<div>`, for example :

```
$(document).on("submit", ".postAjax", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).LoadingOverlay("show");
    data = $(this).serializeObject();
    var element = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(newCommentData){
            /* do some process here to transform your newCommentData array into html code */
            $(element).next(".comments").append(newCommentData);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, if you want it to be cleaner, you could have an hidden 'div', with the same model as a comment div, but with each content replaced by patterns ( ex : `%commentTitle%`, `%commentBody%` ). Then each time you post a new comment, you could get that hidden `div`, and replace patterns with your comment data. That way, if you change comment section structure later, the JS script will still work the same way, without adjustments needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The result returned is JSON, but there is a problem, I render my comments sections with the "render" function of twig like that : 
{{ 
render(controller('KM\\CommentBundle\\Controller\\CommentController::CommentAction',{ 'id': post.id })) }} so the data returned is directly integrated in the page, I can't return only the data on a blank page et by the way append it. So if you have a better solution than "render" to integrate my comments on the page I take

Comment: I don't get your point. The comment section being rendered like that is unrelated. Javascript runs post rendering. So whatever html code is generated by your render, you can happend to, just inspect elements to see class names / elements.

Comment: My bad, append work perfectly, but now, how to append only on the good "comments" class and not all the comments class ? And thank you

Comment: I edited my answer so it appends only to the next element having .comments class. Best way would be wrapping each form/comments section in a div though, so you could browse through parent's elements.

Comment: That's strange, the code doesn't work with `$(this).next(".comments").append(data);` but work on all comments class with `$(".comments").append(data);`, but I think it's a minor JS problem and you gived me enough help to fix it by myself, thank you so much !

Comment: Indeed, my bad, $(this) refers to the jqXHR object inside the success callback. Added the reference to this outside of the callback, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("submit", ".postAjax", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).LoadingOverlay("show");
    data = $(this).serializeObject();

    var $comment = $(this).next(".comments");

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(){
            $comment.append("<div />");
            $comment.last("div").load(window.location.href + " .comments");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That work only on the last ".comments" class of the page, so if I post a comment on the first form of the page, the comment append at the last ".comments" class and not the first ".comments" class :/

Comment: @Kodmit in which event are you triggering the ajax call?

Comment: There is the actual code, it's triggered with submit : `$(document).on("submit", ".postAjax", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).LoadingOverlay("show");
        data = $(this).serializeObject();

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success:function(data){
                 $(".reloadZone").append("<div />");
                 $(".reloadZone div:last").load(window.location.href + " .reloadZone");
            }
        });
` (I have edited the post)

Comment: It load but nothing appear, when I do a console.log on $comment, I have this : "n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: form.postAjax]" It's normal ?

Comment: @Kodmit there was typo, updated answer .comment should be `.comments`

Comment: Now it's work but the other comments of other posts append under the new comment posted, I start to think it's not possible with load and I'll have to find a solution to return the comment with the .append function

Comment: Remove load and just append the new comment in .comments